# Word-Usage: "The newspapers dedicated long/large/ample spaces in their columns."

Tags: word-usage

I have a text that translated in English sounds like this:

> "All newspapers **dedicated long/large/ample spaces in their columns** to that event."

Does such a sentence sound well in English or it should be modified?

Comment: I'd use "**for** the/that event". I might have a preference for the other words, but I do not think it matters. They all work.

Answer (score 2):

In your sentence "space" should be singular

> All ***the*** newspapers dedicated *lots of space* in their columns to that event.

In turn,

> dedicated **long** spaces

not quite correct, eventhough you may mean lots of column inches

> dedicated **large** spaces

if you mean "in the article's columns" then the space is usually not referred to as "large", advertisements spanning columns can be referred to as "large"

> dedicated **ample** space

may not be correct since "ample" is the same as "sufficient" which would not have the meaning of "a lot". "the meaning you are trying to get across is

> dedicated **lots of** space in their columns to that event

none of the phrases are idiomatically correct.

Comment: Is "All the newspapers dedicated lots of space in their columns to that event." idiomatically correct? Can I use this version instead of my rough translation or not? After "In turn" you listed four case, not three, and ended by saying that "none of the phrases are idiomatically correct".

Comment: @RobertWerner I would stick with "dedicated ample space" since it implies sufficient space to meet the need, while "lots of space" means just that.

Comment: @RobertWerner Instead of "space" one would usually use "coverage", especially for news. "The newspapers dedicated large amounts of coverage to that event".  The problem with "large spaces" is it usually means the "space" on a newspaper page, like a full page advertisement is a "large space".